# Insert multiple countdown on the popup of a marker leaflet map

Tags: javascript, html, json, leaflet, countdown

My goal is to show on each popup marker the countdown based on the Json (obj.time).
The coountdown has to be showed on the `<div id='demo'>`
If i insert a single countdown for all the `<div id='demo'>` is working but not with multiple value.

I tried to concatenate the obj[i].id to the id = 'demo' to have multiple id for each countdown
like this `<div id='demo"+obj[i].id+"'>`
Then i did the same with the 
`document.getElementById("demo"+obj[i].id).innerHTML = hours + "h "+ minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";`

The Error that i receive is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at (index):215`

Here is my project https://jsfiddle.net/tiziako/wpo32g6a/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put a new loop in the interval function:

```
var x = setInterval(function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
     if(document.getElementById("demo"+obj[i].id)){
        // Get today's date and time
        var now = new Date().getTime();

        // Find the distance between now and the count down date
        var distance = new Date(obj[i].time).getTime() - now;

        // If the count down is finished, write some text and continue loop
        if (distance < 0) {
            document.getElementById("demo"+obj[i].id).innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
            continue;
        }
        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
        document.getElementById("demo"+obj[i].id).innerHTML = hours + "h "+ minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

      }
    }
}, 200);
```

Also you can set the interval faster, then it will show the timer faster, if you open a popup.

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/7fkpvzta/